# Convert complex structure of map and list into JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a Map>>>>
or something similar Map>
I need to covert this into JSON.

So my use case would be to convert an object which can be a map or list which has generic element of map or list and this can go recursively to any number of times.
The leaf element would be integer or string.

Is there any ready made way i can do this in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It is easy plug-and-play library for serialization/deserialization of JSON. It will handle natively java collections.

It will also help you once you need to deserialize the JSON eventually (however, it needs a bit of more effort toward deserialization of generics)

Comment: GSON might work , but then we should speify the structure of the data structure right. Like Map<list<String,String>> . Here , i have no idea on the structure of the object.

Comment: @VineethMohan When using GSON you can just do `Gson gson = new Gson(); String serialization = gson.toJson(yourMegaComplexMap);` It will work out of the box for any complexity of a map.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create using

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(map);
```

JSONObject is provided by Json.org

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: here Map<String, String> could be actually Map<String, List<Map<String,String>>> , or any recursive combination. That is not taken care by JSON.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Jackson's streaming API's to parse json and create object ?
Something like this
http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object jsonMapper(Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map map = (Map) obj;
        for (Object entryobj : map.entrySet()) {
            Entry entry = (Entry) entryobj;
            entry.setValue(jsonMapper(entry.getValue()));
        }

        return new JSONObject(map);

    } else if (obj instanceof List) {
        List list = (List) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
            Object o = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, jsonMapper(o));
        }

        return new JSONArray(list);
    } else { //string or integer
        return obj;
    }
}
```